# Homebrew Python not installing setuptools

Tags: python-2.7, homebrew, osx-mavericks

This is all on an iMac OSX 10.9.2

When doing a Homebrew install of python2.7 everything appears to be creating correctly. However upon finishing and attempting anything with pip or easy_install I keep getting the following error:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Brewed python with the same results. I also ran the install with -v which produced the following:

```
==> Verifying python-2.7.6.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz checksum
==> Pouring python-2.7.6.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.6.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Python demo
  /usr/local/share/python/Extras

Setuptools and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
  pip install --upgrade pip

You can install Python packages with (the outdated easy_install or)
  `pip install <your_favorite_package>`

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps` to symlink these to /Applications.
==> Finishing up
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/smtpd2.py smtpd2.py
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/smtpd2.7.py smtpd2.7.py
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/smtpd.py smtpd.py
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pythonw2.7 pythonw2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pythonw2 pythonw2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pythonw pythonw
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python2.7-config python2.7-config
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python2.7 python2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python2-config python2-config
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python2 python2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python-config python-config
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python python
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pydoc2.7 pydoc2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pydoc2 pydoc2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pydoc pydoc
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pip2.7 pip2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pip2 pip2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pip pip
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/idle2.7 idle2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/idle2 idle2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/idle idle
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/easy_install-2.7 easy_install-2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/easy_install easy_install
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/2to3-2.7 2to3-2.7
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/2to3-2 2to3-2
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/2to3 2to3
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/share/python python
ln -s ../../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/share/man/man1/python2.7.1 python2.7.1
ln -s ../../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/share/man/man1/python2.1 python2.1
ln -s ../../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/share/man/man1/python.1 python.1
ln -s ../../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current Current
ln -s ../../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 2.7
ln -s ../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources Resources
ln -s ../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python Python
ln -s ../../Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers Headers
ln -s ../../Cellar/python/2.7.6 python
ln -s ../Cellar/python/2.7.6 python
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6: 3790 files, 59M
```

I noticed that the Homebrew Python page indicated that "brew install python" should create a site packages folder at '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'. However when I navigate to '/usr/local/lib' and use 'ls -a' there are no folders pertaining to python.

brew doctor reports no errors

Thank you in advance and please let me know what additional information may be needed.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else runs into this I did manage to find a solution from the following page:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27515

It is apparently a bug in this most recent build. Doing a

```
brew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

appears to do the trick.

Tom

Comment: Worked for me, after ```brew uninstall python```. Thanks!

Comment: Still works on 10.13, got the Azure CLI working—thanks for the tip!